# pydub append - clarification of under the hood behaviour

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, pydub

I've been using pydub to concatenate short sound files into a larger sound file. The basic code for this looks like this:

```
def permuPhrase(iterations, joins): # Builds a single phrase and does various permutations of it
sampleSet = entryMatcher()
sampleSet.inputVars()
sampleSet.match()
concat = 0
if len(sampleSet.results) != 0:
    for x in range(iterations):
        for i in range(joins):
            rand = rn.randint(0, len(sampleSet.results)- 1)
            choice = str(sampleSet[rand])
            concat += (AudioSegment.from_wav(source+choice+affix))
        numIter = str(x) # convert parent for loop to string for naming .wav files.
        concat.export(newDir+numIter+affix, format="wav") # export
else:
    print("No samples matched")
```

My question is this. In the API it states there is by default an 100ms crossfade. However, the example given below suggests that if you use a + operator to concatenate samples it uses no crossfade. I was wondering if anyone can clarify this? I've linked the API as copying the example was not readable. It's under AudioSegment(...).append().

> #### AudioSegment(…).append()
>
> Returns a new `AudioSegment`, created by appending another
>   `AudioSegment` to this one (i.e., adding it to the end), Optionally
>   using a crossfade. `AudioSegment(…).append()` is used internally when
>   adding `AudioSegment` objects together with the `+` operator.
>
> By default a 100ms (0.1 second) crossfade is used to eliminate pops
>   and crackles.
>
> ```
> from pydub import AudioSegment
> sound1 = AudioSegment.from_file("sound1.wav")
> sound2 =AudioSegment.from_file("sound2.wav")
>
> # default 100 ms crossfade
> combined = sound1.append(sound2)
>
> # 5000 ms crossfade
> combined_with_5_sec_crossfade = sound1.append(sound2, crossfade=5000)
>
> # no crossfade
> no_crossfade1 = sound1.append(sound2, crossfade=0)
>
> # no crossfade
> no_crossfade2 = sound1 + sound2
> ```
>
> **Supported keyword arguments**:
>
> - `crossfade` | example: `3000` | default: `100` (entire duration of `AudioSegment`)   When specified, method returns number of frames in X
>     milliseconds of the `AudioSegment`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can confirm that concatenation using the `+` operator doesn’t apply any cross fade (and in fact [calls the append method with crossfade=0](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/blob/71a19bd1bbf5a43b7d94cfdbd26d0ffbc7a5f456/pydub/audio_segment.py#L350))

The reason for that design decision was to allow using sum() and reduce() and other similar methods to put a bunch of chunks back together without altering the total duration (due to the crossfade overlaps)