# Playing two audio files in order without time delay

Tags: python, text-to-speech, wav, pyaudio, mixing

I am creating a program to turn text into speech (`TTS`).

What I've done so far is to split a given word into syllables and then play each pre-recorded syllables.

For example:

> INPUT: [TELEVISION]
>
> OUTPUT: [**TEL** - **E** - **VI** - **SION**]

And then the program plays each sound in order:

```
First:   play TEL.wav
Second:  play E.wav
Third:   play VI.wav
Fourth:  play SION.wav
```

I am using `wave` and `PyAudio` to play each wav file:

```
wf = wave.open("sounds/%s.wav" %(ss), 'rb')
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(...)
data = wf.readframes(CHUNK)
stream.write(data)
... etc.
```

Now the problem is that during the playback there is a delay between each audio file and the spoken word sounds unnatural.

Is it possible to mix these audio files without creating a new file and play them with 0.2s delay between each audio file?

Edit: I tried Nullman's solution and it worked better than just calling a new wf on each sound.
I also tried putting a crossfade following [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50938152/pydub-append-clarification-of-under-the-hood-behaviour).

Comment: try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52702015/7540911) its supposed to join your files **in memory** so you don't write the result to disk and there wont be a delay between them

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to join two wav files using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890703/how-to-join-two-wav-files-using-python)